# Terraform. helm_release resource is not displayed in "helm ls" output

Tags: terraform

Terraform apply produces this output:
`module.helm-services.helm_release.php-nginx: Creation complete after 1s [id=php-nginx-php3]`, where php3 is `terraform.workspace` and `.Release.Namespace`. 
My understanding that terraform should be actually calling helm under the hood, so helm release should appear in `helm ls` output - but it's not there. I checked `helm ls --all` as well and searched other namespaces, but the release is missing.

Here's the sample code:

```
resource "helm_release" "php-nginx" {
  name  = "php-${terraform.workspace}"
  chart = "${var.path-to-helm-charts-repo-locally}/php-nginx
  namespace = terraform.workspace
  depends_on = [var.db_depends_on, kubernetes_namespace.namespace]
  values = [
    file("${var.path-to-helm-charts-repo-locally}/php-nginx/values/default.yaml")
  ]

  timeout = 120
  recreate_pods = true
  wait = false

  set {
    name  = "image"
    value = var.php-nginx-tag
  }

  set {
    name  = "domain"
    value = "net"
  }

  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = "1"
  }
}
```

```
$ terraform version
Terraform v0.12.24
+ provider.aws v2.53.0
+ provider.helm v1.0.0
+ provider.kubernetes v1.11.1
+ provider.null v2.1.2
+ provider.vault v2.9.0
```

```
$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.5", GitCommit:"89bd14c1541fa93a09492010030fd3699ca65a97", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.16.5", GitCommit:"89bd14c1541fa93a09492010030fd3699ca65a97", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

Comment: It kind of sounds like a false negative for the error, or false positive for the success, depending upon your perspective. I would think the Terraform API call to Helm for the create operation followed by the read operation to determine success would have a longer duration than one second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after couple days of investigation, I specified the exact version of helm_provider which this used to work with:

```
provider "helm" {
  version = "0.10.4"
}
```

It doesn't work with versions v1.0.0, v1.1.0 and v1.1.1 though. 
With v0.10.4 releases appear in `helm ls` output